# How to pass mixin param to nth-of-type in Less?

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I'm setting number of columns by passing `@var` to my mix-in like this:

```
.author-card(@numberOfCards) {
    width: 100% / @numberOfCards - 2%;
    padding-bottom: 165% / @numberOfCards - 2%;
}
```

And I want to have a `margin-right: 2%` for each column except for the last in row. So, I try to do the following:

```
.author-card(@numberOfCards) {
    width: 100% / @numberOfCards - 2%;
    padding-bottom: 165% / @numberOfCards - 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    &:nth-of-type(n * @numberOfCards) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

At this point Less compiler fails to compile this.

**Can I achieve this in Less? Maybe there is any other way to do this?**

I get the following error:

> ParseError: Unrecognised input in myStylesheet.less

Comment: See [Selector Interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation). E.g. `&:nth-of-type(@{numberOfCards})`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform selector interpolation, you need to put the variable within curly braces like below:

```
.author-card(@numberOfCards) {
    width: 100% / @numberOfCards - 2%;
    padding-bottom: 165% / @numberOfCards - 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    &:nth-of-type(@{numberOfCards}) { // note the change.
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

[Selector Interpolation - Syntax Reference](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Selector-Interpolation)

Comment: Harry, is it possible to have nesting here? For example I have a mix-in inside of a mix-in and I want to pass @{numberOfCards} to the nested mixin. Is this possible? Thx

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi: I am not sure if I understood your query properly mate, but please check if [this demo](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/eluot) helps you. Here the `nth-of-type` is also populated using a parameterized mixin.

Comment: I've already found a solution to my particular case. Anyway, thx for example.